# Can't access LAN host from the firewall

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, nat, route

I have a problem I cant seem to comprehend, here's the thing: I want to have access to a LAN server on 192.168.100.32 from the firewall (192.168.1.100). This network is managed by eth0, and I can (obviously) access any host within that network without problems.

However, I am unable to access it from the WAN interface (192.168.0.254, that is, eth3). Here's the Nmap scan results for each interface.

$ nmap 192.168.100.32 -e **eth0** // 443/tcp **open**  https

$ nmap 192.168.100.32 -e **eth3** // 443/tcp **filtered** https

```
IPTables: 
Chain PREROUTING
DNAT   tcp  --  eth3 any anywhere anywhere  tcp dpt:https  to:192.168.100.32 


Chain POSTROUTING
MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth3    anywhere             anywhere
```

$ ip route

- 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.100.1
- 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.254

The weird thing is that 192.168.100.32 has access and is able to ping both 192.168.0.1 (gateway IP) and 192.168.0.254 (eth3, firewall interface)

I think it could be an ip route issue, but I don't know how to set it up correctly.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "I cant access my server". Do you mean HTTPS ?

Comment: I don't see any error here.

Comment: Yes, I mean HTTPS (I have setup port forwarding on my gateway to 192.168.0.254 - the firewall) and I should be able to access my LAN host from the Internet...

Comment: Why are you trying to masquerade in both directions? I'm surprised this passes any traffic at all.

Comment: Yes the masquerade is in a way. I can't quite get the picture yet. So you gateway and firewall are different machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch / gateway for your WAN interface probably has [Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) disabled and is refusing to route LAN traffic to the WAN interface back to the LAN.

Comment: Indeed, the problem was situated at the gateway level.
I reset it and reconfigured it and everything's working fine.
@Michael Hampton the masquerade for eth0 was a test.